# Upgrading .NET Core application from .NET 5.0 to .NET 7.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, upgrade, .net-5, .net-7.0

I have a project which has a backend api on .NET 5.0 and a frontend on React.js. I'm trying to upgrade the project to .NET 7.0.

This is the code from `startup.cs` which throws an exception after I upgrade the target framework to .NET 7.0:

```
 app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
            {
                routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel(app.ApplicationServices));
                routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection(); 
            });
```

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name'

I'm using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` (7.5.7); I tried upgrading this to latest version but it caused more reference issues.

I need assistance on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out the way to resolve this.

I used the [link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/796) provided by @bmo and updated **Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData** to **7.5.12**.
Then found another error on Entity framework for that I updated **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstraction** to **7.0.0**, then updated **Microsoft.Extensions.Options** to **7.0.0** and then finally upgraded **MySql.Entity.FrameworkCore** to **7.0.0**.

After that my project migrated from .Net 5.0 to .Net 7.0 without any errors and so far its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

That package has been deprecated as it has critical bugs, but this [solution](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/796) may will be working with you

Comment: _"That package has been deprecated"_ - can you please add some link which supports the claim?

Comment: @bmo I followed the link you shared and upgraded Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData to version 7.5.12 and now getting a new exception
"System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' threw an exception.
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethods' threw an exception."

Comment: @IntelligentCancer which Entity framework version do you use?

Comment: @GuruStron Here you can see [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.OData/5.8.5?_src=template#readme-body-tab)

Comment: @bmo that is not the package mentioned in OP. It does not even have the used version.

Comment: @bmo I was using MySql.Entity.FrameworkCore 5.0.3.1 and upgraded it to 7.0.0